# How to start specific audio stream on button with js

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

have 2 audio streams and 2 buttons:

```
<audio id="audio1" src=""></audio>

<audio id="audio2" src=""></audio>

<a href="" onClick="play1()">BUTTON 1</a>

<a href="" onClick="play2()">BUTTON 2</a>
```

And I want that when I press BUTTON 1, AUDIO 1 starts to stream, and while the AUDIO 1 is playing if I press the BUTTON 2 then the AUDIO 1 must be stopped and AUDIO 2 starts to stream..

Here is the code I tried but the only thing I get is that when I press BUTTON 2, AUDIO 2 starts to stream, but AUDIO 1 will not stop working at that moment

```
function play1(){
   var audio1 = document.getElementById("audio1");
   audio1.play();
   audio2.stop();
}
function play2(){
   var audio2 = document.getElementById("audio2");
   audio2.play();
   audio1.stop();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare audio1 and audio2 variables as global variables. Here is the example:

```js
var audio1 = document.getElementById("audio1");
var audio2 = document.getElementById("audio2");
function play1(){
   audio1.play();
   audio2.pause();
}
function play2(){
   audio2.play();
   audio1.pause();
}
```

```html
<audio id="audio1" src=""></audio>

<audio id="audio2" src=""></audio>

<a href="" onClick="play1()">BUTTON 1</a>

<a href="" onClick="play2()">BUTTON 2</a>
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: audio2.stop is not a function, and
Uncaught TypeError: audio1.stop is not a function

Comment: instead of stop() you could try with:
audio1.pause();

Comment: I just change .stop() in .pause() and now its working, thank you!